# easeljs add bitmap to stage multiple time at different position

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I just started working with the easeljs library. I have created a canvas with a stage and it works.

I want to add bitmaps as buttons and add them side by side in the bottom on the stage.

I have tried with the following, but it place the bitmaps on top on each other.

```
var button = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("largebrick"));
        var contentWidth = document.getElementById("content").offsetWidth;
        var contentHeight = document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight;
        var container = new createjs.Container();
        stage.addChild(container);

        stage.enableMouseOver(10);
        for(var i = 0; i <10; i++){
            button.x = 0 + button.getBounds().width * i;
            button.y = contentHeight - button.getBounds().height;

            button.addEventListener("mouseover", function() { document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer'; });
            button.addEventListener("mouseout", function() { document.body.style.cursor = 'default'; });
            button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {addBricks(button); });
            container.addChild(button);

        }
```

I hope some of you guys can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things here. You need to create a new instance of the button inside the loop, otherwise you are just moving the original instance of button on each iteration. In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4cLng/), I simplified everything a bit by using a shape, but you could easily do the same with your Bitmap.

```
var xPos = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var button = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("largebrick"));
    button.cursor = "pointer";

    button.x = xPos;
    button.y = contentHeight - 50;
    xPos += 60;
    container.addChild(button);

}
```

Also, createjs supports defining cursors as a property of a display object like so

```
button.cursor = "pointer";
```

which should simplify your code a little.

Comment: Off course, stupid me. Did something similar in another file the right way :(
But thx for the hint with the cursor :) i will look into that.

Comment: btw how can i add eventlistener to each button and know which button have been clicked?
If I do it like this button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {addBricks(button); }); then I always gets the last button.

Comment: You could use the "name" property to help identify which button is being clicked [link](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_name). Then in the event handler, event.target will be your button. You can do a switch on event.target.name.